# Admin Bar menu item that executes Javascript but does not reload the page?

Tags: javascript, admin-bar

I added a menu item to the Admin Bar that executes some Javascript to show debug information. The problem is that clicking this item also reloads the page. How can I prevent this?

I was trying to speed up my debug & dev stuff and wanted to add a class to my main wrapper div using jQuery.

#### Step 1:

Add styles to your head

```
function my_admin_bar_script_def( $script ) {
$script = '
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery("li#wp-admin-bar-showdebug").click( function() {
            jQuery(".wrap").toggleClass("showdebug");
        } )
    } );
';

return print $script;
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_admin_bar_script_def', 11 );
```

#### Step 2:

Add a admin bar menu item:

```
function my_admin_bar_class_switch() {
global $wp_admin_bar;

$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( 
    array( 
         'parent'   => 'theme_options'
        ,'title'    => __( 'showdebug', TEXTDOMAIN )
        ,'href'     => '' // **interesting problem over here**
    ) 
);
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'my_admin_bar_class_switch', 70 );
```

#### Problem:

Every time you trigger your toggle function you'll fire up the link and reload the page. Therefore you'll get the initial trigger again. Replacing the link is not possible, because in the `$args` array for the `add_menu()` function you only define the `href` and the link will be printed anyway. Filters or hooks? Not available.

Comment: You could move the "Solution" part to an answer, then we can all vote on it - or even add alternative solutions?

Comment: @Jan Fabry - done. Good idea. Unmarked the answer as solution.

Comment: I re-wrote the intro so it looks like a real question, and is more likely to attract Google searches for similar problems. If you don't like it, feel free to edit or rollback!

Comment: @Jan Fabry - No, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `return false` in that Javascript function the click will not be propagated and the page will also not reload.

Even better, [you can specify a `onclick` attribute for a menu item](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php#L51). So you definition would become this:

```
function my_admin_bar_class_switch( &$wp_admin_bar ) {
    // $wp_admin_bar is passed by reference, you don't need the global var
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( 
        array( 
             'parent'   => 'theme_options'
            ,'title'    => __( 'showdebug', AHF_LANG )
            ,'href'     => '' // This can stay empty
            ,'meta'     => array(
                'onclick' => 'jQuery(".wrap").toggleClass("showdebug"); return false;'
            )
        ) 
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'my_admin_bar_class_switch', 70 );
```

In that case you don't need to hook up the `onclick` event yourself. I see two other possible errors there: `wp_head` is an action, not a filter, so by returning the script it won't be printed. Also, you depend on `showdebug` being part of the `id`, but because you don't specify the ID it is generated from the title. If that string is translated this ID won't stay the same.

Comment: excellent solution. +1. I wrote the code above as an example. In my theme i don't use `wp_head()`, but some custom filter that is set after a `$var` that get's printed after the hooked function, so in my case it's fine that way, but i updated the example. Ad ID) Right. Completely oversaw that trap. thanks!

Comment: @kaiser: Yes, I thought you had some custom way to add that Javascript. You still need to add `<script></script>` to your current output.

Comment: yes and the cdata stuff :)

Comment: i just exchanged my approach with yours and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot. I guess i can mark this as solution.

Comment: @kaiser: And that's the wonder of using WPSE as [a technical blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault) where you post your answers to your own daily problems: not only can you pro-actively help others, you can even get better solutions from others!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

Simply set `'href' => '#'` to link to a not defined anchor to avoid page reloading.

I know this is really simple, but it took me nearly an hour to get on the right track (thinking too much about filters and hooks to modify the output), so here's my share.